# country name [plural or singular]

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I saw this news headline:

[Japan defeat Scotland to progress to RWC Quarter Final](https://www.scottishrugby.org/fixtures-and-results/internationals/2019-20/rugby-world-cup/13oct/japan-v-scotland)

Can country names be treated as plural nouns? This [dictionary](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/japan?q=Japan) says it is a singular noun.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain something about what leads you to think that country names can be treated as plural nouns? "[Details, please](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/q/439/6700)."

Comment: Oh, I think I figured it out: you must be asking why "defeat" agrees with "Japan".

Comment: I wrote you an answer but since this question got marked as a duplicate, I posted it [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/227605/6700).

Comment: OK. Thanks. If this question should be deleted, please delete it. "India has or India have" is probably not an informative title, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In British sport journalism, teams are usually plural, and national teams are named as the nation.