# If 'public' is a collective noun then why isn't 'people'?

Tags: nouns

I find that the word **public**  is regarded as a collective noun and the subsequent verb is said to be used in singular form.
Then why is not **people**  a collective noun though the meaning of the two words is quite same?

Comment: I think this might help. When thinking of *public* in the sense of "people in general", try to think of it as a set of items, as opposed to thinking of *people* as items.

Comment: These two words mean *similar* things, and they have a good deal of overlap; but that is not quite equivalent to saying that they mean the *same* thing. Moreover, neither is used exclusively as a collective or count noun. Each has a wide range of uses, as you will soon learn if you look them up in a variety of dictionaries.

Comment: People can be a collective noun: see [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10891/6951), especially the part under the horizontal line, and [this answer](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10892/6951). *Public* can take either a singular or plural noun, depending on whether the speaker is considering 'the public' as a group or as each individual within 'the public' (similar to 'team' and many other words').

Answer (score 5):

A "collective noun" in this sense is a grammatical term not a semantic one. So-called "collective nouns" can take either plural or singular verb agreement:

- The team are asking for you.
- The team is asking for you.

*People* meaning merely a number of persons cannot be used in the same way. It is always plural and cannot take singular verb agreement:

- People are asking for you.
- *People is asking for you. (ungrammatical - singular verb agreement)

**Edit**:

There is the other meaning of *people* meaning something similar to *nation* or *cultural group*, however, which could be considered a collective noun. (See StoneyB and  δοῦλος's comments below). Notice that this has distinct and regular singular and plural forms:

- The Berbers are **a proud people**.
- The different **peoples** of the Northern hemisphere.

As with other collective nouns, the singular form may be used as the subject of a sentence but occur with plural verb forms:

- A people are as healthy and confident as the stories they tell themselves.

Much less commonly it can also occur with singular verb agreement:

- As long as a people is compelled to obey, and obeys, it does well.

*Hope this is helpful!*