# There 'is' people or There 'are' people?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

What is the correct form?

> There **is** people
>
> There **are** people?

Kindly, explain your answer.

Comment: Depends on the context, but most often "are" is the verb form to use because "people" designates a multitude of individuals; just tradition, I guess.

Comment: Also, if you use the singular, you should probably use "a" before "people": "There is a people" (i.e. "a nation").

Comment: related to this question: [Is “people” a countable or a non-countable noun?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-people-a-countable-or-a-non-countable-noun)

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand the dependence of the context to the question. Are there times that word "people" gets "is" and times that it gets "are" ?! If so, I would like to know and to learn. Thank you

Comment: A simple look at Oald would show you that "people" can be plural meaning persons and that there is a second use people/peoples meaning all people of one language/race etc.  http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/people_1?q=people

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**People** is the [plural form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plural) of **person** (see [irregular words](https://www.engvid.com/irregular-plural-nouns/)), therefore, it has to be referred as plural.  People are always minimum two, that's why we should say:

> "There **are** people who like to help." [*Correct* ✅]

rather than

> "There *is* people who like to help." [*Incorrect*❎]

Answer (score 2):

People is usually used in the sense of "multiple persons tied by some common thread", hence it's used as a plural. Why is "people" used that way, and why is "community" not used that way? I can't tell you, because I don't know myself!

Examples

> *We* the people
>
> The people of California vote today - as against -Every person in California *voteS* today
>
> When oppressed, people rise up vs. When oppressed a person *riseS* up.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -3):

i think both are right. 
if you use "people" as a collective noun such as "family" then you may use "is."
but for the word "people" itself is considered as plural, to use "are" is more usual.