# A people - is it correct?

Tags: usage, articles

Puls Biznesu reported that the idea of the book was to give **a people** an opportunity to communicate abroad in a universal language - pictures.

Is it right to place the indefinite article "a" before the plural noun "people". If it's correct, why?

Source: http://thenews.pl/1/10/Artykul/252710,Graphic-dictionary-helps-refugees

Comment: _People_ is not necessarily a plural, as any good dictionary will show you. In this case, _people_ is a countable noun in the singular.

Comment: What's the meaning?

Comment: Any [dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/people) will tell you that... see meaning 4 in the link.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should close this question as "answerable by dictionaries" or as a duplicate of http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-people-a-countable-or-a-non-countable-noun, but my opinion is it should be closed one way or another.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "people" a countable or a non-countable noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-people-a-countable-or-a-non-countable-noun)