# the or zero article in the given context?

Tags: articles

> Prejudice is still prevalent in this generation, and it is one of the
>   engines that fuels the novel to transcend time with such popularity,
>   affecting ***(the)*** people who suffered similar discrimination presented in the
>   story.

I just do not know if I have to use the definite articles in the given position.

The use of definite article seems justified, for it is people who suffered similar discrimination out of all usual common people.

However, the use of zero article seems more adequate when I consider that I am referring to all people who suffered similar discrimination.

I think it is just from which perspective we frame this people.

But which one should I use?

Comment: I feel like you're missing part of the sentence... "suffered similar discrimination *as is* presented in the story." perhaps?

Comment: More context would be nice. Many times, the use of articles is dependent upon information found outside the sentence it is used in.

Comment: I think it has something to do with the relative clause being a specified occurrence vs a generalization. "I want to kill the people who stole my bike." vs. "I don't trust people that have stolen bikes."

Comment: @whitedevil Could you tell us what novel is reviewed in the text you cite here? Is the review itself available online?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sarah Costa, in a post at our sister site ELU, proposed a guideline which is germane here, and which I will gently paraphrase as:

> Without a context that clarifies whether the sentence relates to a specific group, the zero article is preferred.

Her entire answer, and the question to which is a response, can be found [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/116202). The commentary following her answer is also of interest,

In this case, because the context *does* define a specific group, the sentence, under this guideline, should include the definite article.

Comment: It is just people in general who suffered similar discrimination that was presented in the story. So is it generalization? Or are we still specifying a group of people?

Comment: @whitedevil _People_ in the sentence refers to those readers who have suffered similarly to characters in the novel. That is a specific group; thus, the definite article.

Comment: Do you think the indefinite article will pass?

Comment: Or is it simply unacceptable?

Comment: @whitedevil The indefinite article will not work here. The definite is called for. "A people" here would be understood as referring to "a people" such "the Russian people." _People_ is a special case with many idiomatic uses. See this [link](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10890/37009).

Comment: Sorry, I meant zero article.

Comment: @whitedevil Since "people" refers here to a specifically defined group, the zero article is not the best option. Read my answer and follow the link.

Comment: I did. But user3169's answer yields the use of zero article, because they are not previously defined according to him/her. But you said that it should refer to a group of the readers of this novel, so the definite article should be used. I think a native speaker will just glance over it and feel nothing wrong with it, but I don't know.

Comment: @whitedevil - No, user3169's answer is the same as mine. "People" here means the _readers who suffered discrimination similar to that presented in the story_. If you **omitted** that part of the sentence, the zero article might work.

Comment: OK. So does zero article sound completely horrendous?

Comment: Um, by "similar to that presented in the story", are you referring to the people, or discrimination? I intended it to refer to discrimination.

Comment: @whitedevil The whole sentence could be written more clearly: _Prejudice is still prevalent in this generation, and it is one of the engines that fuels the novel to transcend time with such popularity, affecting the people who suffered discrimination similar to that presented in the story._ "People" refers to **the specific group of readers who we suffered the same discrimination as presented.** Here the definite article makes that clear. With the zero article, it's certainly acceptable; it's just not as clear.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe both are OK, but since you have defined the "people" as being a specific group "presented in the story", I would use *the*.

However, if you left off "presented in the story", and the "people" were not previously defined, I would not use *the*.