# "They were a powerful people"

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

I'm reading The Wind in the Willows by Kenneth Grahame and there's the following phrase: "They were a powerful people, and rich, and great builders."

However, I've googled a rule: Plural nouns can be used with the definite article or no article at all; to use an indefinite article would be incorrect.

Does it mean that "people" here is a singular noun? Is this because the phrase refers to people as a tribe/community?

Comment: Yes. _A people_ has a meaning distinct from _people_ on its own - it means a nation or ethnic group.

Comment: Use a dictionary. People: people noun [ countable ] all the men, women, and children who live in a particular country, or who have the same culture or language" Cambridge Dictionary.

Comment: Related [Is “people” a countable or a non-countable noun?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10890/9161)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right in thinking that it refers to ‘people as a tribe/community’. In this case, ‘a people’ means ‘the entire group of people (that usually has something in common e.g. language, culture, ethnicity etc)’.

I recently read the first chapter in *The Cambridge Encyclopedia of the English Language* by David Crystal and came across the same usage of ‘a people’:

> Before the Anglo-Saxon invasions (§2), the language (or languages) spoken by the native inhabitants of the British Isles belonged to the Celtic family, introduced by **a people** who had come to the islands around the middle of the first millennium ad [...]